# List as a member of structure has associated with another structure(list has a object of another structure as parameter)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

code is in vb.net

```
Structure FeeComponent 
    Public id As Integer
    Public sName As String
    Public oFee As List(new FeeDetail) 
End Structure
```

another structure

```
Structure FeeDetail

    Public rollNo As Integer
    Public address As String
    Public age As Integer

End Structure
```

in a function a sql query is executed and result is stored in Reader  and i want to add some details to the main Structure FeeComponent in the below manner

```
Dim Retval As New List(Of Idemo.FeeComponent)
Dim Fee As New List(Of Idemo.FeeDetail)

Dim Temp As New Idemo.FeeComponent
Dim Fees As New Idemo.FeeDetail

While Reader.Read

            With Temp
                .id = Reader.Item("id")
                .sName = Reader.Item("Name")
With Fees
                .rollNo = Reader.Item("roll")
    .address = Reader.Item("add")
    .age = Reader.Item("age")
            Temp.Fee.Add(Fees)
        End While
```

shows error on the Temp.Fee.Add(Fees) line 
how to correct the code i have done everything i could but i am not able to correct the code.
I just started using vb so please help
error msg is 
     System.NullReferenceException: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Firstly, never tell us that an error occurs without providing details.  You are provided with an error message for a reason.  Why keep that a secret from us?

Comment: As for the error, where do you ever assign anything to `oTemp.oFee`?  The answer is nowhere.  You never assign a `List(Of S_FeeDetail)` to `oTemp.oFee` so there's nothing to call `Add` on.

Comment: What you do is up to you but your naming conventions are truly horrendous.  What it the point of all the "o" prefixes?  Do you notice how none of the properties you use from the .NET Framework have an "o" on them and the world doesn't fall apart?  Also, notice how none of the structures have "S_" on them and still the world doesn't fall apart?  I'm not fan of Hungarian Notation when it's used properly but even less so when it's abused like this.  It makes code harder to read, not easier. I very nearly didn't answer this question because reading the code was so unpleasant.

Comment: sorry for the naming convention but thanks for the help

Comment: You don't have to apologise.  Like I said, what you do is up to you.  I really don't think you're doing yourself any favours like that though.  Hungarian Notation had its place but today, using an IDE like Visual Studio, that place is no more.  What you're doing goes beyond Hungarian Notation though, and not in a good way.